# Call the base class implementation

Tags: c++, qt, class, subclass

I was able to simulate the Right-Click event by subclassing the `QTableWidget`:

header file:

```
#ifndef QRIGHCLICKTABLE_H
#define QRIGHCLICKTABLE_H

#include <QTableWidget>
#include <QMouseEvent>

class QRightClickTable : public QTableWidget
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    explicit QRightClickTable(QWidget *parent = 0);

private slots:
    void mousePressEvent(QMouseEvent *e);

signals:
    void rightClicked();

public slots:

};

#endif // QRIGHCLICKTABLE_H
```

cpp file

```
QRightClickTable::QRightClickTable(QWidget *parent) :
    QPushButton(parent)
{
}

void QRightClickTable::mousePressEvent(QMouseEvent *e)
{
    if(e->button()==Qt::RightButton)
        emit rightClicked();
}

QRightClickTable *button = new QRightClickTable(this);
ui->gridLayout->addWidget(button);
connect(button, SIGNAL(rightClicked()), this, SLOT(onRightClicked()));


void MainWindow::onRightClicked()
{
    qDebug() << "User right clicked me";
}
```

Now, right-click works correctly, but there are other problems with QTableWidget: all other mouse events, such as the left click to select a cell, no longer work.
Can you help me? I know I need to call the base class implementation in my override of mousePressEvent, you could show me how with a little piece of code?

Answer (score 2):

Change your event handler like this :

```
void QRightClickTable::mousePressEvent(QMouseEvent *e) {
    if(e->button()==Qt::RightButton) {
        emit rightClicked();
    } else {
        QTableWidget::mousePressEvent(e);
    }
}
```